# What is the correct way to specify margin and padding in CSS?

Tags: css, margin, padding

Are these valid values for `margin` and `padding` in CSS?

```
margin: 0px 10px;
padding: 5px 0px 10px;
```

I thought that you always had to specify all four sides:

```
margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
padding: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
```

Also, when I write CSS like `margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;` my editor IntelliJ warns me that the `px` is redundant. Should properties like this be written differently?

---

### For anyone reading this post, the answer lies in all of the responses. Each clarifies the shorthand aspect. Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can specify fewer than 4 as a 'short-hand', which sets several properties to the same value at the same time; for example, [the CSS documentation says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin):

```
body { margin: 2em }         /* all margins set to 2em */
body { margin: 1em 2em }     /* top & bottom = 1em, right & left = 2em */
body { margin: 1em 2em 3em } /* top=1em, right=2em, bottom=3em, left=2em */
```

---

The dimension (e.g. `px`) is redundant when (only when) the value is `0`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity on the 0 value.

Answer (score 13):

They are all *correct*, they are just different ways of writing something.

Long notation:

```
margin|padding: top right bottom left;
```

Shorthand notations:

```
margin|padding: top left&right bottom;
margin|padding: top&bottom left&right;
margin|padding: top&right&bottom&left;
```

And for the second question: If you write `0px`, the unit is redundant, because zero is zero, regardless of unit, so you can just as well write `0` without any unit.

Also see [the CSS documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin)

Comment: Very concise @Florian Peschka

Comment: I remember this by using 'TRBL' - i.e. 'trouble' - top right bottom left

Comment: @AdamMarshall ... or "Clockwise assigment"

Answer (score 4):

It is not mandatory that you specify all the four attributes all the time. In your case `margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;` can be better written as `margin-right: 10px;` if all other margin values are already 0. Also you need not add `px` if the value is 0.

Have a look at the shorthand notations also,

```
margin: 0px; (top, right, bottom, left - 0px)

margin: 2px 4px; (top and bottom - 2px, right and left - 4px)

margin: 2px 4px 6px; (top - 2px, right and left - 4px, bottom - 6px)
```

Comment: This is very useful as I never knew that for the attributes you could have anything less than TRBL. It was always my understanding that margin itself was the shorthand to avoid using all of the other identifiers such as margin-top etc.

Answer (score 1):

The way that you choose to pick **depends on the layout**.

If **every side is different**, then you would do each side differently.
`margin: 10px, 15px, 20px, 25px;` ( of course you could use this any time, but that's the best example ).

If the **tops and sides are the same** then just do the first number for the top and bottom and the second number for the sides.
`margin: 10px, 20px;`

And if you want **all 4 sides** to have the same margin, then
`margin: 10px;` does all 4.